# Building an Openfire XMPP External Component - use Tinder or Whack?

Tags: xmpp, openfire, whack

I'm trying to build an external component for the Openfire XMPP server, but I'm a bit confused between Tinder and Whack. Tinder seems to be the newer library and has the AbstractComponent interface which Ignite Realtime are recommending over the standard Component, however, whenever anyone talks about building an external component, they seem to be using the Whack library.

Should I be using Tinder or Whack? Or a bit of both?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tinder utilises the Whack library and wraps the component in an abstract component interface so you don't have to implement all the methods for handling all types of packets if you don't need to.

Have a look at the source for the weather example.

It's also worth looking at the whack source to see how it handles the packets as this is what is ultimately connecting to your server and sending packets.

Personally I use the externalcomponent manager from whack and setup an abstract component using tinder which is exactly what the weatherabstract example does.

That's the best place to start.

Comment: As the project lead for both Tinder and Whack, I can confirm that James is spot on: use Whack to create an external component.

Comment: Ha, never noticed THE @Guus commented on my answer, good to know I wasn't spouting BS. I still use the weather example as a starting point for the external components.